# JQuery Form Wizard - Finish Button With Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I seem to be having trouble linking the finish button on my Jquery Form Wizard within my Flask App to a link. I tried creating a simple alert to test the functionality but I can't even get that.

I'm sure I'm missing a step somewhere but I can't seem to track down the problem.

HTML:

```
       <script src="../static/jQuery-Smart-Wizard/js/jquery.smartWizard.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        // Smart Wizard
                        $('#wizard').smartWizard();
                        //$('#range').colResizable();

                        function onFinishCallback(){
                            $('#wizard').smartWizard('showMessage','Finish Clicked');
                        }
                    });
                    </script>
```

jquery.smartWizard.js:

```
   onFinish: function () { alert("Finish Clicked!") }, // triggers when Finish button is clicked
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

==EDIT==
I have build new pen for you to check it out,,

http://codepen.io/mkdizajn/pen/YZmEWZ?editors=1010

I successfully added finish button and called alerf on it.. this code works for sure!

```
// define FINISH BUTTON
var btnFinish = $('<button></button>').text('Finish').addClass('btn btn-info btn-fnsh');

// Smart Wizard
$('#smartwizard').smartWizard({
    selected: 0,
    theme: 'default',
    transitionEffect: 'fade',
    showStepURLhash: true,
    toolbarSettings: {
        toolbarPosition: 'both',
        toolbarExtraButtons: [btnFinish]
    }
});

// define a action for finish btn
$('.btn-fnsh').on('click', function(){
    alert('Finish clicked!')
})
```

Comment: No luck. Adding it to steps doesn't activate the button when clicked.

Comment: I've edited my answer,, you will see,, you need to define html for button first, then link it via `toolbarExtraButtons` and then define action for it outside scope..

Comment: @ashap did you get the chance to check out new code?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Ya, code works. The problem now is the finish button is now enabled at every step. 

How can I incorporate the disable method into the code so that the finish button is disabled on every step except the last?

Comment: this as separate question,, I built a `alert` callback for you, like your question says

Comment: you might like to check my codepen,, I added check for you to see how you can control finish button :)